# Update To MvvmCross 5.2 Throws Navigation Service Compiler Error On Navigate Method

Tags: navigation, mvvmcross

I updated MVVMCross from v5.x to v5.2 and had to update my viewmodel navigation service code to change the **Initialize** method required by the navigation service for parameter passing to the new **Prepare** method. However, now I am faced with the following compilation error on the **Navigate** method of the IMvxNavigationService when trying to navigate using a parameter object:

> Error CS1501: No overload for method 'Navigate' takes 1 arguments

As far as the documentation goes, I thought my code was correct but am I missing something? My code is as follows...

**ViewModelA**:

```
public class ViewModelA : MvxViewModel
{    
   ...

   public void DoNavigate()
   {
      var navigationService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>();
      navigationService.Navigate<ViewModelB, PageNavParameters>(
         new PageNavParameters
         { 
            PageDisplayType = MyPageDisplayTypeEnum.PageDisplayType1, 
            ObjectID = "someIDstring"
         }
      );
   }
```

}

**ViewModelB** (inherits from a super class viewmodel):

```
public class ViewModelB : SuperViewModel
{...}
```

**SuperViewModel** (inherits from a base viewmodel (which in turn inherits from MvxViewModel), and because it already has a base, SuperViewModel implements the IMvxViewModel interface):

```
public class SuperViewModel : BaseViewModel, IMvxViewModel<PageNavParameters>
{

    public void Prepare(PageNavParameters pageNavParameters)
    {
        CurrentPageParameters = pageNavParameters;
    }

    public PageNavParameters CurrentPageParameters { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

My navigation service code was functioning properly before the update and change to the **Prepare** method, however I'm a bit stumped here. It seems as if the **Navigate** method is looking for ViewModelB to be passed as a parameter, however a type can't be passed here, and I am already strongly typing the method itself with ViewModelB in the call. Apologies in advance if it's something minor I missed, and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What if you move `IMvxViewModel<PageNavParameters>` to the `ViewModelB`? Does that work?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Nope, moved it to ViewModelB along with the Prepare method but same error.

Comment: Do you have a repo to reproduce?

Comment: Unfortunately not since it's a private repo for the company, but I can possibly try to make a second public repo with part of the code to reproduce since we can't build until we figure this out.